# doctrine:schema:update is at broken state with indexes and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

I came to a project running symfony 5 with doctrine and mysql database at version 5.6.

Command `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` outputs alot of ADD CONSTRAINT queries trying to add foreign keys to tables.

Some of them for example:

```
ALTER TABLE user_show_access ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2015CD5AD0C1FC64 FOREIGN KEY (show_id) REFERENCES shows (id);
ALTER TABLE user_show_access ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2015CD5AA76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id);
ALTER TABLE user_track_access ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CE6796BFA76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id);
ALTER TABLE user_track_access ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CE6796BF5ED23C43 FOREIGN KEY (track_id) REFERENCES tracks (id);
ALTER TABLE tracks_video ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B620A4B1DE12AB56 FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES users (id);
ALTER TABLE tracks_video ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B620A4B116FE72E1 FOREIGN KEY (updated_by) REFERENCES users (id)
```

But if i try to run this queries in database they are not applicable, failing on errors like:

```
[2023-08-31 13:25:12] [HY000][1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint
[2023-08-31 13:25:12] [HY000][150] Create table '{xxx}/#sql-859_42977d4' with foreign key constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.
```

I have 2 questions since im not a database specialist and i usually rely on `doctrine:schema` commands to do the work for me. If i try to create local database and run these queries above clean database, everything works as expected, so my guess is that dev before me did something to database manually and basically got it into this state.

1. How do i fix this, is there a way to do it? Since im absolutely clueless if i should try to add the foreign keys myself, or if there is way to basically reset the database FKs and let doctrine do its thing?
2. What kind of actions were done to get the database to this state.

Database on this project is super slow, fastest queries starting somewhere from 600ms to execute. My guess is that fixing this would really fasten the whole project by alot.

Thank you in advance for any tip.

I tried to look into tables structure myself and found out that there is actually PK for `users` table on id.

This is CREATE table query of a user outputed from `doctrine:schema:update` on a clean database

```
CREATE TABLE users (id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', user_avatar_id CHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, initialized TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, remote_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, facebook_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, avatar_url VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL, birthday DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, gender VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, geo_latitude DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL, geo_longitude DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL, google_id VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL, google_url VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL, email_verified TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, news_duration INT DEFAULT NULL, you_id INT DEFAULT NULL, microsoft_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, podcastovatko_id INT DEFAULT NULL, is_active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E9E7927C74 (email), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E99BE8FD98 (facebook_id), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E976F5C865 (google_id), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E986D8B6F4 (user_avatar_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is CREATE table query for table `user_show_acess`

```
CREATE TABLE user_show_access (id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', user_id CHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', show_id CHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', valid_to DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_2015CD5AA76ED395 (user_id), INDEX IDX_2015CD5AD0C1FC64 (show_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And these are queries trying to add constraints to tables

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1483A5E986D8B6F4 FOREIGN KEY (user_avatar_id) REFERENCES users_avatars (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE user_show_access ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2015CD5AA76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id);
ALTER TABLE user_show_access ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2015CD5AD0C1FC64 FOREIGN KEY (show_id) REFERENCES shows (id);
```

Comment: It is most likely that in **any** of those tables you are adding foreign constraints, a row contains data that can not be linked to your one of your constraints. Eg. lets say `tracks` only contains id 1 and 2. However, in table `user_track_access` you have a row linking data to `tracks` id=3. Before the constraint, this was not an issue. However, with constraint, the constraint can not be added, since there id=3 does not exists. This can explain why you can excute the constraint on an empty database but not on a database **with** data.

Comment: I looked into it more after your suggestion and im not really sure if thats the case.
If that would be the case query like this `SELECT user_id
FROM user_track_access
WHERE user_id NOT IN (select id from users)` would show me the problematic id, or am i missing something?

This outputs empty results and for example `user_show_access` is completely empty.

Comment: It was an example, you should check that for all of your constraints. In addition, for your "non problematic" example, in order to entire rule out my suggestion, executing adding that specific constraint **should** work then. Furthermore, try to find the constraints that are problematic. In your update, you even add more constraints. We do not know ***which*** constraint fails, I doubt that they all fail (especially when some tables are completely empty, like you suggested).

Comment: Yes i ran individual ALTER TABLE on empty user_show_access table and it still fails, also i ran multiple SELECT to find id that is not present in referencing table and couldnt find a single one.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326040/there-is-no-index-in-the-referenced-table-where-the-referenced-columns-appear-as) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072547/cannot-find-an-index-in-the-referenced-table-where-the-referenced-columns-appear)? The same error message, did you make sure all of your id's are indexes?

Comment: So I finally figured it out, i tried all your methods and non of them were the problem, keys were matching and there was no missing keys aswell, sadly we learned the hardway after our database was crashing on memory problems, when we figured out that some tables have different encodings, so after fixing this problem and having the two columns in same encoding, it all ran smoothly, ofcourse greatly improving our performance